# flux cannot find kustomization path, stat /tmp/XXXXX/kustomize/monitor-nats/overlays/dev: no such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes, charts, flux, cicd

I'm getting this error while trying `flux reconcile kustomization monitor-nats`.

here's more info

local k8s cluster version v1.23.4 created using `kind create`

inside main flux repo:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: monitor-nats
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 10s
  path: ./kustomize/monitor-nats/overlays/dev
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: monitor-nats
```

---

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
  name: monitor-nats
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 20s
  ref:
    branch: master
  # url: ssh://git@github.com/XXX/fluxcd.git
  url: https://github.com/XXX/fluxcd.git
  secretRef:
    name: nats-auth
```

from my monitor-nats application
`cat kustomize/monitor-nats/overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: default
resources:
- ../../bases
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You see this file, but look about the paths. Are you sure that you have opened `kustomize/monitor-nats/overlays/dev/kustomization.yaml` from your `/tmp/XXXX` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today. The solution was, that I had a *.sourceignore* file on the root of my git repository. It was configured to exclude the path used by kustomize.

```
# Exclude all
/*

# Include manifest directories
!/apps/
!/clusters/
!/infrastructure/
!/monitoring/
```